# How to add Custom Controls in razor view in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

**How to add Custom Controls in razor view in mvc 4**

There is a project requirement to add custom control in razor view in mvc4 but i am unable to do it. So need help

Is there any possibility to add custom controls in razor view mvc4. If yes then how is it possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by controls but you could use Html Helpers:

```
@helper ProductListing(List<Product> products) {
   <ul id="products">
   @foreach(var p in products) {
       <li>@p.Name ($@p.Price)</li>
   }
   </ul>
}

<div>
    @ProductListing(Model.Products)
</div>
```

See this post written by Scott Gu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx